# UI Automator Viewer not responsive

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

I can launch UI Automator Viewer but the UI doesn't allow mw to take screenshot 9UI is irresponsive).
Any idea what is going on?

Note:

- I am working on MAC book pro and did an upgrade to Big Sur.
- After this update, I couln't launch Ui Automator Viewer. I followed this thread by changing my swt.jar (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/46388/uiautomatorviewer-not-running-on-mac-big-sur)

[image]

Comment: In the terminal when launching, I noticed a NullPointerException:     
        NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)